# Storyboard: Segmented Control + Two Table View Controller with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

How do I properly organize this space StoryBoard?. 
I need when I open tab TabBar I have a table with data. But while there is a switch on top of Segmented Control, which switched to the table.

At the same time I need to table serving different controllers. And the tables had their own Navigation Controller.

If I tap on a table cell, the Segmented Control removed and remains familiar Navigation Controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];

AppDelegate *appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController=vc;
```

Comment: Please note that I have an application like TabBar. 
And then set the connection between my example and SecondViewController UITableViewController (push, modal custom)?